# airflow statsd prometheus mapping rules

Tags: airflow, prometheus, statsd

I have tried to use statsd_exporter as a bridge to export airflow metrics to prometheus.

Airflow.cfg:

```
statsd_on = True
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 9132
statsd_prefix = airflow
```

prometheus.yml

```
  - job_name: 'airflow'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9135']
```

start statsd_exporter as:

```
 ./statsd_exporter --web.listen-address=":9135" --statsd.listen-tcp=":9132" --log.level=debug
```

Seems mapping rule is missing as there is no airflow related metrics got in prometheus[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLvLK.png)

Would someone have any sample mapping rule for airflow statsd_exporter to prometheus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find mappings in the official repo https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/chart/dockerfiles/statsd-exporter/mappings.yml

There's also this slightly tweaked version which drops unmatched metrics https://github.com/astronomer/ap-vendor/blob/main/statsd-exporter/include/mappings.yml